Convergence diagnostics for discrete parameters in MCMC
I produced MCMC samples for a finite mixture model. This includes latent classes, which are not only discrete but also lack an ordering.
Now I am trying to assess the algorithm's convergence. While the traceplot makes sense, I am unsure if autocorrelation or Rhat do. For the Rhat statistic I am using the newly proposed one from 2019 by Vehtari et al. It is conveniently implemented in the 'posterior' package in R.
My first is question is what metrics, like Rhat, are appropriate for a factor variable like latent classes. (Or perhaps Rhat already is but I am overlooking something.) And second if this is conveniently implemented anywhere. I am on a somewhat tight schedule for this project.

Each latent variable $z_i$ should be uniformly distributed over ${1,\ldots,K}$ if label switching is achieved by the MCMC algorithm. Cf, e.g., our 2000 JASA paper.

Fascinating perspective, I took label switching to be a symptom instead of a feature. You argue that a well-converged MCMC sampler actually does switch labels, meaning that it approaches a uniform distribution if you let the number of samples grow, if  understand correctly?

You mention how the label switching complicates inferring the means. Then you offer two solutions. Have you seen any advances in the past two decades that supersede them?

In our Handbook of Mixture Analysis, there are several approaches proposed. Incl. the initial one by Peter Green I really like, namely to treat the $m$ component parameters (eg $(p_k,\mu_k,\sigma_k)$) as a point in $\mathbb R^m$ and to use clustering on the resulting MCMC sample.

Thank you, I will look into implementing this in the final version of my algorithm. Once I've debugged an updating rule for a variance parameter with an inverse-Gamma($\epsilon, \epsilon$) prior. Green's approach sounds far More statistically sound and transparant than imposing ordering constraints in each step of my Gibbs sampler. As I am doing now.

Yes, do not impose constraints while running the MCMC as it only slows it down...
